# Why do I get an unexpected port value in C?

Tags: c, sockets, memory, dynamic

I'm writing a program which gets an identifier from params, creates an UDP socket, gets a port, and prints `<identifier>: <port>`. 
Then, receives some identifiers and ports from stdin and store them in memory. 
In the code below, the problem is that the port variable (`udp_port`) get 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

typedef struct process {
    char id[80];
    int port;
    int me;
} process;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc<2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Use: process <ID>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* NODES */
    process * processes;
    int num_process = 0;

    /* CONECTION */
    int udp_port;
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr, local_addr;

    /* STDIN READS */
    int port;
    char line[80],proc[80];

    /* I/O buffer mode */
    setvbuf(stdout,(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*80),_IOLBF,80); 
    setvbuf(stdin,(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*80),_IOLBF,80); 

    /* Prepare socket */
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(0);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(fd == -1){
        perror("SOCKET");
        return 1;
    }

    if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1){
        perror("BIND");
        return 1;
    }
    getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addr, (socklen_t *) sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    udp_port=ntohs(local_addr.sin_port);   // Gets port

    fprintf(stdout,"%s: %d\n",argv[1],udp_port);   // Prints identifier: port

    // Reads from stdin
    for(;fgets(line,80,stdin);) {
        if(!strcmp(line,"START\n"))
            break;            

        sscanf(line,"%[^:]: %d",proc,&port);
        num_process++;
        processes = realloc(processes,num_process);
        strcpy(processes[num_process-1].id, proc);
        processes[num_process-1].port = port;

        if(!strcmp(proc,argv[1])){ /* Thats me */
            processes[num_process-1].me = 1;
        }else{
            processes[num_process-1].me = 0;
        }
    }   


  return 0;
}
```

But, it gets a correct value (random port) when I comment the realloc line and related lines, like this:

```
    // Reads from stdin
    for(;fgets(line,80,stdin);) {
        if(!strcmp(line,"START\n"))
            break;            

        sscanf(line,"%[^:]: %d",proc,&port);
        num_process++;
        //processes = realloc(processes,num_process);
        //strcpy(processes[num_process-1].id, proc);
        //processes[num_process-1].port = port;

        if(!strcmp(proc,argv[1])){ /* Thats me */
        //    processes[num_process-1].me = 1;
        }else{
        //    processes[num_process-1].me = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: One issue: you are passing to `realloc` uninitialized pointer which is dangerous.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in `C`. It can hide Errors and gives no benefit.

Comment: Check the return value of socket functions like `getsockname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashes if used as it is. Because you pass to realloc uninitialized pointer. Initialize `processes` to NULL:

`process * processes = NULL;`

EDIT:

Otherwise, the udp_port is non zero. And `getsockname` returns  Bad address.
Try the following for `getsockname` to be successsful:

`socklen_t tmp = sizeof(struct sockaddr);`

`getsockname (fd, (struct sockaddr *) &local_addr,&tmp);`

Answer (score 0):

Checking the return value of `getsockname` function I get a `Bad address` error.
The problem was that the last parameter in `getsockname` was incorrect:

```
getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addr, (socklen_t *) sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

`sizeof` returns a `socklen_t` instead of `socklen_t *`. I fixed this like this:

```
socklen_t size_sa = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
if(getsockname(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&local_addr, &size_sa) == -1){
    perror("GETSOCKNAME");
    return 1;
}
```